# If statement with arithmetic comparison behaviour in bash

Tags: bash

I'm learning bash and I noticed something weird I can't (yet) explain. At school I learned that an if statement evaluates 0 as true and 1 as false, so it can be used with the status code from an other command. Now is my question: Why does this happen:

```
echo $((5>2)) #prints 1
echo $((5<2)) #prints 0
if ((5>2)) ; then echo "yes" ; else echo "no" ; fi #prints yes
if ((5<2)) ; then echo "yes" ; else echo "no" ; fi #prints no
```

This doesn't seem logical. How does bash know i'm using an arithmetic expression and not another command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$((...))` is an arithmetic *expression*; it expands to the value of the expression inside the parentheses. Since it is not a command, it does not have an exit status or return value of its own. A boolean expression evaluates to 1 if it is true, 0 if it is false.

`((...))`, on the other hand, is an arithmetic *statement*. It is a command in its own right, which works be evaluating its body as an arithmetic expression, then looking at the resulting value. If the value is true, the command *succeeds* and has an exit status of 0. If the value is false, the command *fails*, and has an exit status of 1.

It's a good idea when learning `bash` to stop thinking of the conditions in `if` statements, `while` loops, etc. as being true or false, but rather if the commands succeed or fail. After all, shell languages are not designed for data processing; they are a glue language for running other programs.

Comment: Hmm, seems like I've used some incorrect terms in my answer. I hope you don't mind me editing to use the correct ones.

Answer (score 7):

You're confusing the output of the command substitution and the return value of the arithmetic context.

The output of the command substitution is `1` for true and `0` for false.

The return value of `(( ))` is 0 (success) if the result is true (i.e. non-zero) and 1 if it is false.

`if` looks at the *return value*, not the output of the command.

Answer (score 2):

From the `bash` manual:

> `((expression))`
>
> The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION. **If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1**. (My emphasis.)

So essentially in a boolean context `((expression))` gives the inverse of what `$((expression))` would give.